# What is `Graphics Pss` in the `adb shell dumpsys meminfo` output?

Tags: android, memory

If you run `adb shell dumpsys <package_name>`, the output contains a section like this:

```
 App Summary
                       Pss(KB)
                        ------
           Java Heap:    65636
         Native Heap:    22216
                Code:     1444
               Stack:     1444
            Graphics:    79332
       Private Other:     6140
              System:    19569

               TOTAL:   195781       TOTAL SWAP PSS:       85
```

What does the `Graphics` metric correspond to?

Answer (score 1):

please refer to [How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

the Debug.MemoryInfo class has full documentation for related fields above~